# How to configure Serilog (in the json file) to log info to file, but verbose to console?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, serilog

Here is my configuration:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel":  "Information"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Here is the C# code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateBootstrapLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting up ...");

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
        .ReadFrom.Services(services)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext());
    ...
}
...
```

My goal is to be able to tweak the configuration file without recompiling the code, if I want to change the log level.

The above configuration sends Debug logs to both the console and the file, though I am trying to send only Info to the console. Does not work - both sinks show Debug.

The version I use is Serilog.AspNetCore 6.1.0

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`restrictedToMinimumLevel` should be inside Args accroding to this [doc](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration):

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel":  "Information"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Tried with a minimal example:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)    
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Debug("Debug");
Log.Information("Info");
```

it works as expected:

[image]